# How to accomplish full record update on Django REST serializer update() method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a model based serializer called RecipeSerializer(). In it I have a create method that looks like so:

```
class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hops = HopAdditionSerializer(many=True)
    fermentables = FermentableAdditionSerializer(many=True)
    style = StyleSerializer()
    yeast = YeastSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        exclude = ()
    def create(self, validated_data):
        recipe = Recipe.objects.create(**validated_data)
        recipe.save();
        return recipe
```

What I'm trying to do is something similar with my update() method. In the documentation they show going through each field one by one and setting the values:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
    instance.content = validated_data.get('content', instance.content)
    instance.save()
```

My model has many fields though. What I'd like to do is pass the validated data to the update method similar to the create method:

```
instance.update(**validated_data)
```

However, I get an error:

```
'Recipe' object has no attribute 'update'
```

Is it possible to update all properties of the instance using the validated dataset without setting each property individually?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can try like this:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    for key, value in validate_data.items():
         setattr(instance, key, value)
    instance.save()
```

**FYI:** a model instance(or object) does not have any method called `update`. But there is [update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#update) method for queryset.

Comment: Yep, I just figured out there is no update method on a model instance. Surprised by that, but the iteration solution will work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@ruddra's answer should solve your problem but if you really still want to use an update method, you can use the queryset's update method this way:

```
Recipe.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk).update(**validated_data)
```

Note that this won't even hit the Recipe model's save method as it uses a bulk update technique